# What's the difference between Data Transformation & Data Manipulation?

Tags: xml, transformation

What's considered XML Data Transformation?

```
<My Perspective> Data transformation combining or rearranging one XML to another
XML doc based on their XSDs. E.g XMLa -> firstName | lastName ===(Tranformation) 
==> XMLb -> fullName = concatenate(XMLa.firstName + " " + XMLb.lastName)
```

I'm using tibco business work & designer to do this.

What's considered XML Data Manipulation?

```
<My Perspective> Data manipulation is the changing of the data within one XML
to another. E.g. XMLa --> UScurrency ===(Manipulation)==> UScurrency * 1.4 
= SGcurrency ( not in xml?).
```

Is this considered manipulation ??

In the case of changing information from imperial to metric (E.g.
length in feet to length in metres / weight in pound to kg & vice
versa), whether this change is to fit another xml or not, is this
considered manipulation or transformation?

Comment: Well, im sorry but I just needed some clarification on the difference between the two a certain project criteria which i need to meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the term *transformation* is used if a completely new output document is created from one or more input documents. A typical example would be a transformation with XSLT, but any process that builds a new document can be labeled as transformation.

The term *manipulation* is used if an existing XML document is altered, that is nodes are added, changed, or removed. This is typically done using the DOM interface.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official definition that distinguishes between these two, as far as I know. I suggest strongly that you go back to whoever assigned you this project and ask them what *THEY* think the terms mean.

(Specific counterexample: In XSLT, the last letter does stand for Transformation, and XSLT can certainly do computation as well as simple restructuring.)